# What GNN architectures exist to do graph classification on dynamic graphs?

Tags: neural-networks, graph-neural-network

As the title suggests, what GNN architectures exist to do graph classification on dynamic graphs? Can you point me to papers / implementations? Some architectures exist to deal with dynamic graphs; for example, [ReNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05530.pdf). But the paper does not tackle graph classification, but instead prediction of later states of the graph. I am looking for something specifically for graph classification (i.e a GNN that can predict a label based on the evolution of the graph with time)